# Facebook mobile (vs. native) users click on feed story but goes to store, not native app

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, mobile

I'm having this issue with our Facebook app both for Android and iPhone.

User is in Facebook mobile (m.facebook.com). User clicks on feed story. Expected behavior- open native iOS or Android app. Behavior: opens Google Play or iTunes Store. App is "installed" but not launching.

Deep linking works native->native. So Facebook native app, when users click on a feed story, open in the native iOS/Android app.

We don't have a mobile web app, but I've setup a landing page with links to Android and iOS.

Any idea if
- this is what is supposed to happen
- some kind of configuration issue?

Comment: could u find a solution ??? I needed some help

Comment: I haven't yet, will post when I do.